# ctrl + click eclipse pydev

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Im trying to follow some python code using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click, but Im trying to follow a classname.run() but it gets 180 results and complains.. are there any plugins that is able to semi-compile the code to be able to find the dynamic object type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure without the full example, but PyDev does a code-analysis to try to discover the actual type. When it goes on to show all the matches in the workspace, it means that it wasn't able to show it (which is usually the case if that was a parameter).

If you have the class name, usually selecting the class name in the editor and doing a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> is the easiest way to go to the class (and in a class <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> is the easiest way to find a method or field).